# Selenium webdriver - Cannot find button inside modal

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, xpath

I cannot click on this button contained in a modal

this is the html

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <button class="btn modal-button full-btn" id="saveexit" type="button">
Save and Exit</button>

</div>
```

Here is the java code:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"saveexit\"]")))
```

I have also tried with:

```
cssSelector: #saveexit
cssPath: html.no-touch body div.remodal-wrapper.remodal-is-opened div.modaliAdesione.remodal.remodal-is-initialized.remodal-is-opened 
div.modal-dialog div.modal-content.modal-custom-content div.modal-footer div.row.text-center div.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12 
button#saveexit.btn.modal-button.full-btn
xpath: //*[@id="saveexit"]
```

this is the error I am getting:

```
Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by ...
```

I also asked a similar question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47944349/1948785)

I am new to Selenium so excuse me if it is a silly question.
Here is an extract of the html code: https://codeshare.io/arLW9q

Please note: if I run `document.getElementById('saveexit').click();` from browser's console it works out

Comment: Is the modal window visible when the code is called?

Comment: @SlightlyKosumi  yes it is

Comment: and if you look for all elements of type button, and output their properties, what do you see?

Comment: how do u mean to do that? do u mean in the browser console via js/jquery or in the selenium project?

Comment: You can find elements by tag name. Maybe there is only 1 input button, maybe there are more - I don't know. Anyway, you can find all input buttons and for each one print out some property of it to console. That way you can see if you are really having the input fields which you expect present and visible onscreen. It's a good debug technique.

Comment: thanks @SlightlyKosumi, driver.findElements(By.id...) is returning a list of 0 elements :(

Comment: I think you need to give more html source code in that case. In particular, dump or pipe PageSource somewhere just before you are making this call to identify your object. Otherwise, we cannot answer your question.

Comment: here is an extract of the html code: https://codeshare.io/arLW9q saveexit is the div I cannot get in selenium

Comment: Based on the HTML you posted, I can't see any reason why the locator you're using wouldn't work. Something else to check is whether your driver's window/frame context is correct. If the HTML you provided is within an iFrame, you must switch the driver context to that frame before trying to locate the button. Ditto if the modal is (for some reason) opened in a new window.

Comment: thanks @VanderLinden, is there a function to know what are all the available windows?

Comment: I don't work much with Java Selenium, but I think getWindowHandles() will give you what you need.

Comment: already tried it and returns just 1 window...

Comment: I would expect all the windows until now...

Answer (score 4):

### Possibilities

I can't see anything wrong with the snippet you shared, but here are a few things to check out.

- The modal is inside of an iFrame. You need to switch focus to the iFrame first before you can read/manipulate anything in it. Can you fill in any of the fields in the same modal?
- There is actually more than one id="saveexit" on the page and the first one is hidden so the selenium is correct. Search the whole source for that string just to be sure (coders love cut and paste and may have put the same ID twice).
- Switch from: *By.xpath("//*[@id=\"saveexit\"]"))* to *By.xpath("//*[@id='saveexit']"))* - Not sure if it'll make a difference, but it takes out some confusion.

**P.S.** iFrame is not the same as window. You need to use the correct methods.

*To count*

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe")).size();
```

*To access*

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame);
```

Comment: unfortunately size of iframe list is 0 length

Comment: not even switching the xpath differently works out

Comment: if I run `document.getElementById('saveexit').click();` from browser's console it works out

Comment: @eeadev, since your question is about wait, what happens if you an explicit wait? Just wait for a certain number of seconds and just click. If it's clickable, you can change the wait to _wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(button));_ and simplify things.

Comment: it happens that button is never found

Answer (score 0):

As per the html code https://codeshare.io/arLW9q you have shared, below are few techniques that we use in the automation testing company for element click:-

```
1.driver.findElement(By.ID("saveexit")).click();

2.driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div//button[@id="saveexit"])).click(); or driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div//button[contains(text(),"SAVE EXIT"])).click();

3.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12 > button#saveexit"));
```

**Note**: Further if you are able to run document.getElementById('saveexit').click(); from browser's console than you can click on the element by javascript:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByID('saveexit').item(1).click();");
```